# Data not rendering with nuxt and storyblok

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, storyblok

Hei. I am creating a website with nuxt and using Storyblok as CMS. I did already 2 pages where I pass the data through it and just works fine. Now I have one( i am creating a discography page) that the data is there ( when I console it) but nothing is rendered...

So I try to in the asyncData to console the data and it shows up. I try to add other component that I had used before and it works just fine..

This is my component

```
<article :to="id" class="discography">
    <div :style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + thumbnailImage + ')'}" class="discography-thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="title">
      <h1 class="test">{{ title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ year }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
...
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    year: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

and the page where it renders:

```
<section class="container">
    <Discography
      v-for="discography in discographies"
      :key="discography.id"
      :title="discography.title"
      :releaseYear="discography.year"
      :thumbnailImage="discography.image"
      :id="discography.id"
    />
  </section>
...
then(res => {
        console.log(res)

        return {
          discography: res.data.stories.map(ds => {
            return {
              id: ds.slug,
              title: ds.content.title,
              year: ds.content.year,
              image: ds.content.image
            }
          })
        }
```

Comment: check your v-for i think it is wrong, u are looping over discograpies and in function u are using discography to asign data

Comment: @MladenSkrbic thank you. Yes i changed the name of it but I didn't update the function.... Thanks again

Comment: are u seeing console.log(reS) in console. Could u post ur whole method here so i can see it. Also idea for refactoring, u could pass whole object to Discography component and then use it in component rather then passing seperate values as props, perhaps it would be more readable and reduce markup.

Comment: @MladenSkrbic all works now. It was indeed the name that was wrong. Yeah, this is my first real website in nuxt so I am blind in some things but actually it make me some confusion to read the code when is divided like this. I have more components with the same way. I will refactor them like you are suggesting. Thanks